# Expected Identifier Error or "("Error

Tags: objective-c

I am making a temperature converter and wanted to improve the app so I decided to add the code that would change the background image according to the output which would be the converted number.  What I want to do is that if my convertedTemperatureLabel.text < 0, the background change to some image I will import and when it is > 0, the background would change into another image.  So I used the following code that gives me the expected identifier error:

```
if ([convertedTemperatureLabel.text doubleValue] < 0) {
NSLog("The temperature is above 0");
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"snowy- grand-canyon-nichols_26007_600x450.jpg"]];
}

else {
NSLog("The temperature is below 0");
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wallpaper_hazybluedots.jpg"]];
}
```

Where is my mistake? And also is the code the one needed for my purpose? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your strings passed to `NSLog` are not instances of `NSString`; they're C strings.

```
NSLog(@"The temperature is above 0");
```

Adding the 'at' sign makes things right.

Your log statements are backwards for what you actually want; if temperature is less than zero, you don't want to say that the temperature is *above* zero. And you *are* missing one condition: What if the converted temperature is zero?

Comment: so I followed your instructions, but still xCode give me the identifier error!

Comment: Are you trying to use UIKit objects (`UIColor`, `UIImage`) in a project that's set up to use AppKit (`NSColor`, `NSImage`)? If you want to write an iOS application, make sure it's set up that way. But if this code you're trying to use came from a iOS project, and you want to make use of it in a desktop application, you need to use `NSColor` and `NSImage` instead. This is a long shot, but I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: Well I originally created the app for iOS. And when I type UIC, xCode automatically gives me UIColor as an option. So I think I am using UIKit objects.  And I just dont seem to be able to get rid of the identifier problem. By the way, is my code correct after all for what I want to achieve ?Tnx

Comment: The error occurs where the "if" and "else" are.  And there is an orangish triangle under "i of if" and "e of else". Thought this would help!

Comment: My .m file type is on default-Objective-C source. is that the one?

Comment: @PedZad If you're getting those errors as you describe, it's possible there's a typo in some other portion of your code that precedes what you provided here. Are these the only errors/warnings you're getting?

Comment: i have two "parse issues" that are labeled with a yellow exclamation mark.

Comment: the thing is that the if and else statement doesn't work at all! And it is confusing because I have other if and else statements that actually work. So is there any other way that I can obtain my goal ?

Comment: @PedZad I think at this point it would be good for you to provide the code that encloses what you originally provided. I'm out of guesses at this point.

Comment: Would you like me to upload my whole .m file?

Answer (score 0):

As trudyscousin said, u should provide NSLog with obj-c strings like this:

```
   NSLog(@"The temperature is below 0");
```

Comment: so I followed your instructions, but still xCode give me the identifier error!